# How can i have If else if in a VF page?

Tags: visualforce

I am defining a class for a TR tag based on some condition.
This works fine  if there is a if and else situation

```
<tr class="{!IF(ISNULL(Eslot.sEvent), 'Free', 'Fill')}">
```

Now i have a third option, ie if Eslot.sEvent has some value , then i need to check if that event has a type = 'Personal' and if its is then need use the class called 'Pers' else use Fill.

I tried something like this

```
 <tr class="{!IF(ISNULL(Eslot.sEvent), 'Free', if(Eslot.sEvent.Appointment_Type__c=='Personal','Pers',Fill'))}">
```

It gives out an error

```
    Error: EL Expression Unbalanced:
```

Any idea how to resolve this? This code already existing piece of code, so i want to do as less  logic changes as possible

Comment: You might want to consider moving the logic to a single method in the controller that returns a String as expressions get more complicated in VF pages, they become harder to maintain and more error prone (as you found out), in my opinion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing an opening quote in `Fill'`. It should be:

```
<tr class="{!IF(ISNULL(Eslot.sEvent), 'Free', IF(Eslot.sEvent.Appointment_Type__c == 'Personal', 'Pers', 'Fill'))}">
```