# How to change Field Label of each fields in a FieldSet

Tags: visualforce

Here in `apex:inputField` I am able to change one label, but I want to change all of them:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Lead.FieldSets.commercial}" var="fs1">
    <apex:inputfield value="{!Lead[fs1]}" 
        label="{!IF(fs1.label== 'Company','Client Name',fs1.label )}">
    </apex:inputfield>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Why do that? It really defeats the puspose of using fieldset. Also not that the fields can have different value in another language translation. Recommend you to use a custom setting instead, where in you can have API name and Label of fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OR(condition1, condition2)` and inside that use if.
or else you can try NESTED `IF` also.. 
[How to Use Nested If in VF Page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21405/how-can-i-have-if-else-if-in-a-vf-page)